# PivotTable, page filter - filtering with date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter Page filter which has date values. But I keep getting error when I use `.PivotFilters.Add type:=xlBefore, value:="5/1/2015"`.
I also tried the code below:

```
Dim nd As Long
nd = CLng(Date - 90)

pvt.PivotFields("startdate").ClearAllFilters
pvt.PivotCache.Refresh
pvt.PivotFields("startdate").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlBefore, Value:=nd
```

But now I am getting *Named argument not found*.

The PivotTable is created successfully but not filtered.

Comment: where do you the `startdate` field in your pivot table? Report Filter? Column Label? Row Label?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman its in Report filter

Comment: Therein lies the problem. Report filter fields behave differently. You may need to loop through the dates in the field and select them if they are before your desired date. Make sure to turn enable multiple items to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a pivot field is used in the `Report Filter` filtering it is different than when it's a `Row` or `Column Label`. See the code below to set your filter criteria on the `startdate` located in the `Report Filter`.

```
Dim nd As Date
nd = CLng(Date - 90)

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Set pvt = Sheet1.PivotTables(1)

With pvt

    .PivotCache.Refresh

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = .PivotFields("startdate")

    With pf

        .ClearAllFilters

        Dim pi As PivotItem
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            If pi < nd Then pi.Visible = True Else: pi.Visible = False
        Next

    End With

End With
```